# Football Match Score Possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

*"In a football match between team A and team B, the final score is team A with $n$ goals, team B with $m$ goals. How many ways can this happen, if we know when team B score their final goal, team A's score was $k$? ($0\leq k \leq n$)"*

I am stuck on where to go; here is my thinking thus far:

If we didn't know $k$, and simply knew the end score, there would be ${m+n}\choose{m}$ possibilities.

But including the extra information is hard. An idea is to split the goals into two sets: those which happen up to team B's final goal, and the $n-k$ that happen after.

Before team B's final goal, I think there would be ${m+k}\choose{m}$ possibilities, because we have a set of $m+k$ total goals and we want to know how many ways we can split it into two sets size $m$ and $k$ respectively. And then after the goal there should be ${{n-k}\choose{n-k}}=1 $ possibilities (it will be a straight run of goals).

Is this all correct? And if so, how do I tie it all together? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct, because we know that the $m + k$ th goal was scored by team $B$. There are $m + k - 1 \choose k$ ways to achieve a score of $k$ against $m - 1$, after which $B$ scores once and, after that, $A$ scores $n - k$ times. Thus, the total number of ways to achieve this simply equals:

$$m + k - 1 \choose k$$

Comment: This makes sense - thank you!